# @Model does not exist in the current context

Tags: model

I changed the target framework from 3.1 to 2 due to DoDaddy not informing me that is the only version they support so I put it back to 3.1. After putting back I get errors all over my project. Mainly on the @Model and Model references and the SelectList command.

Any help please

Comment: Did all the nuget packages restore correctly?

Comment: I think so, how do I check please? It seems that all my model references in my views are failing. Any help much appriciated.

Comment: It seems like I've lost the link from the view to the model by changing target version. Unfortunately I am still learning and can't work it out.

Comment: Everything in my web app now says does not exist in this context. Event in my _ViewImports file for the @addTagHe;[er